# unknown attribute 'name' for page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object

Hello I am super new to coding & ruby on rails. I am using the Lynda.com "Ruby on rails 3 essential training" I am on section 8 on video called `"One-to-many associations"` for those who what tutorial I am referencing.

I keep running into this error

```
"ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'name' for Page"
```

The command I am running is
`first_page = Page.new(:name "First Page", :permalink => "first", :position => 1)`

When I run the command without

`":name => 'First Page'" as first_page = Page.new(:permalink => "first", :position => 1)`

the error goes away.

So that is my confusion is, why giving the object a name causing this error.

Comment: Is there a column in the page table called "name"?

Comment: go to  your `db/schema.rb` to check whether the `pages` table has `name` column first.

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate` to make sure your table is created? What does your migration file look like? That is the file in your_app/db/migrate that ends with pages.rb.

Comment: I have migrated earlier to make sure the pages table was created.
Once again I am new to coding so please give a little slack. So by column in the page table called name you mean like this? The copy and paste below is from my schema.rb file

create_table "pages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "subject_id", limit: 4
    t.string   "permalink",  limit: 255
    t.string   "name", limit: 10            <-------- "name" in column?
    t.integer  "position",   limit: 4
    t.boolean  "visible",                default: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"

Comment: I edited the "column" and added t.string "name", limit:10 because it was not there. I thought adding it will fix the issue but it still persists. I am still getting the same error. Did I add it to the wrong spot?
create_table "pages", force: :cascade do |t|

thank you all for trying to help me out. 

    t.integer  "subject_id", limit: 4

    t.string   "permalink",  limit: 255

    t.string   "name", limit: 10

    t.integer  "position",   limit: 4

    t.boolean  "visible",                default: false

    t.datetime "created_at"

    t.datetime "updated_at"

Comment: To be honest with you guys I've moved on from trying to name my pages. I just left them unnamed. I moved forward but it seems that run into another error. Idk if this tutorial is outdated or the material is not clicking. Probably a combination of both...I am a nurse for a living, I feel as if I can follow directions and understand complex materials, but coding is another level. I'm pulling what little hair I have out haha

Answer (score 1):

You misplaced the `:` in setting the name key-value pair:

Instead of:

```
first_page = Page.new(:name "First Page", :permalink => "first", :position => 1)
```

Try this (assuming your Ruby version is >= 1.9):

```
first_page = Page.new(name: "First Page", permalink: "first", position: 1)
```

Comment: I ran the code the way you wrote it first_page = Page.new(name: "First Page", permalink: "first", position: 1) but I am still getting the error listed in my original post. 
Thanks though